# how to restrict access to certain properties of an entity based on the requester

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC and am building a web api for a mobile application. I am using asp.net web api and entity framework.

I have read a lot about authentication and authorization for web api. The part i am unclear about is how to prevent access to specific properites of an entity depending on who is trying to access the property.

e.g. lets say my model has a bookmarks entity - the entity would look like the following:

```
public class Bookmark
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public User Owner { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsPublic { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateJoined { get; set; }
    public string Address {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Bookmark> Bookmarks { get; set; }
}
```

i have two questions.

1) While anyone should be able to access ../mysite/username/bookmarks, if its a different person requesting the bookmarks of another person, then i'd only return the public bookmarks. where should this logic live? I belive, this business logic should be in the model. So should i create another set of classes like DTO to handle this business logic? I haven't seen any examples of adding such methods to the entity framework classes themselves.

2) I noticed then when i return a set of bookmarks from lets say a bookmarkController, because there's a User property in Bookmark, it also returns the properties of the User - including information i don't want to share - like the address.

I am not sure how (by nulling the properties before responding or assigning them to different DTOs) and where i should handle this scenarios (adding methods in DTOs specific to the usecases or in the controller).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For you second question you can set the user object to be virtual. This enables lazy loading so the properties shouldn't be pulled unless you access them directly.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if it's a different person requesting the bookmarks of another person and pass that to the logic layer. (something like:  `GetBookMatdData(int bookmarkID, bool isSamePerson)` )
then if `isSamePerson` is False you know not to return the User data.

Answer (score 0):

Returning DTOs in stead of EF entity classes is usually better. It adds an abstraction so you will never (inadvertently) publicly expose properties you don't want to expose. (Think of what may happen if you add sensitive properties later).

So I would definitely return `BookMarkDto`s. You can build the returned collection by a union of all public bookmarks and the login user's own bookmarks. (A union is an implicit distinct). Thus, nobody will ever see someone else's private bookmarks.